# if script runs true restart/run next part

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to get the script to restart the computer when the script returns $true, I'm planning to run the script in SCCM or task scheduler. 
I was going to get the SCCM to restart the computer if it returns $true but don't know how to so now I'm trying to add a restart within the script itself  but don't know how to add it correctly .

```
function Test-PendingReboot
{
 if (Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\RebootPending" -EA Ignore) { return $true }
 if (Get-Item "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired" -EA Ignore) { return $true }
 if (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager" -Name PendingFileRenameOperations -EA Ignore) { return $true }
 try { 
   $util = [wmiclass]"\\.\root\ccm\clientsdk:CCM_ClientUtilities"
   $status = $util.DetermineIfRebootPending()
   if(($status -ne $null) -and $status.RebootPending){
 return $true
   }
 }catch{}

 return $false
}

If $true) {
  Restart-Computer

  }  Else {
  exit 
}
```

Comment: it looks like this `If $true) {` should be something like this `If (Test-PendingReboot) {`. [*grin*]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If (Test-PendingReboot -eq "true")
{
 your code for restart
}

Comment: Given that `Test-PendingReboot` returns a _Boolean_, you shouldn't compare it to a _string_ (while it works in this case, there is no reason to use a string); the immediate fix is to use `if (Test-PendingReboot -eq $true) ...`; however, simply `if (Test-PendingReboot) ...` will do.

Comment: thank you but it doesn't seem to work, could you give me the full script please.

Comment: @TAmoorAHmed _it doesn't seem to work_ means what? Do you get any error messages? Did you put your brackets in correctly, so not like in your code `If $true)`?

Comment: I added the below at the end and powershell just hangs:
     if (Test-PendingReboot -eq "true") {Restart-Computer -Force}
     }

Comment: anyone able to help

Answer (score -1):

This sample code should work for you.

```
function reboot
{
    function Get-property
    {
    try { 
            if (Get-ItemProperty 'hklm:software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\policies\system' -name enablelua)
            {
                $value = "true"
            }
            else{ $value = "false" }
        }
    catch{}
    return $value
    }
    Get-property

    If (Get-property -eq "true") 
    { your code for restart }

}

reboot
```