# Change function to run when running power shell script

Tags: powershell

The script below only works when run as a function I'm trying to change it so when i run .\SCript.ps1 in power shell the script checks the reg keys and if it finds a value it restarts if not it exits, what is the best possible way to convert the script below to do this ?:

```
function Test-PendingReboot1{
function Test-PendingReboot
{
 if (Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\RebootPending" -EA Ignore) { return $true }
 if (Get-Item "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired" -EA Ignore) { return $true }
 if (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager" -Name PendingFileRenameOperations -EA Ignore) { return $true }
  try { 
   $util = [wmiclass]"\\.\root\ccm\clientsdk:CCM_ClientUtilities"
   $status = $util.DetermineIfRebootPending()
   if(($status -ne $null) -and $status.RebootPending){
     return $true 
   }
 }catch{}
  return $false
 }
   if (Test-PendingReboot -eq "false") {Restart-Computer -Force}
    }
```

Comment: Question like `what is the best possible way` can get primarily opinion-based answers and are off-topic. Your choice of all the PowerShell tags (which mutually exclude the other) needs an explanation. I don't see a progress to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55125957/if-script-runs-true-restart-run-next-part) or incorporation of the comments there.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your simplest ask, to turn your code example into a script, you can do the following:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param()

function Test-PendingReboot() {
    $local:ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
    $cv = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion'
    if (Get-ChildItem -Path "$cv\Component Based Servicing\RebootPending") {
        return $true
    }
    if (Get-Item -Path "$cv\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired") {
        return $true
    }
    if (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager' -Name PendingFileRenameOperations) {
        return $true
    }
    $util = [wmiclass]'\\localhost\root\ccm\clientsdk:CCM_ClientUtilities'
    $status = $util.DetermineIfRebootPending()
    if ($null -ne $status -and $status.RebootPending) {
        return $true
    }

    $false
}

if (Test-PendingReboot) {
    Restart-Computer -Force
}
```

As a footnote, you should not treat booleans as strings (your `-eq "false"` comparison).

Comment: thank you for your reply i want the system to restart when true, i by mistakenly put false. what should i change so it restarts when true ? thank you again.

Comment: @TAmoorAHmed See my update, you would just call the function and if it's true, it'll enter the `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your function takes any arguments so you could make it a self-calling script simply by adding

```
Test-PendingReboot1
```

to the bottom of your function, then it will call itself when you call your script